# How do you call an outer functions return after an inner async function finishes running?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

This is my code:

```
.filter('getUserName', function(User) {
    return function(id) {
       User.get({ _id: id }, function(user) {
           return user.name;
       });
    };
});
```

I want the middle function to return `user.name`. `User.get` is asynchronous, and so I can only return from the middle function once the inner asynchronous function finishes running.

I know 2 ways to run code once the asynchronous code finishes running: using the success callback, or the success promise. However, both of those create an inner function, hence my problem - I don't know how to run code that

- Only runs once the asynchronous function finishes and
- Returns from the middle function.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I doubt you can use a $resource in `filter`. Why would you need to anyway?

Comment: `{{skim.author | getUserName}}`. `skim.author` is an `id` and I'm trying to convert it to the appropriate name. I could do it in the controller but I have to do it in multiple places so I figured that a filter would be appropriate (rather than doing it in multiple controllers). Regardless, I'd still like to know how to do what my question asks in the abstract in addition to solving my problem

Comment: You can't return a promise as a result of the filter (which is what you would have had to do if it worked like that). Filters are meant to be synchronous.

Comment: @charlietfl console logging `user.name` works, so I think `$resource` works.

Comment: it's not that `$resource` doesn't work it's that filter needs to be synchronous in order to filter the model data in real time

Comment: You might consider writing a small directive for this, if you're looking for reusability. I don't think filters can be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible fit for a filter, but just as an intellectual exercise, you could have the filter return some default behavior (i.e. return blank) until data is fetched, and once fetched apply the filter. This would necessitate the filter to be `$stateful`, which is very wasteful - it will run on every digest cycle.

```
app.filter("foo", function($timeout){
  var cache = {};

  function genFoo(input){
    $timeout(function(){
      cache[input] = input + "foo!";
    }, 1000);
  }

  var filter = function(input){
    if (input in cache) return cache[input];
    genFoo(input);
    return "";
  };

  filter.$stateful = true;
  return filter;

});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uNq1RZQU3shgdPRfHu8z?p=preview)

DO NOT do this as a filter :)

Comment: is $stateful something new in 1.3? Just started noticing it but only recently and have used angular back to about 1.04

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-8

Comment: I guess they made an improvement not to watch for stateless, and kept the watch for stateful.

Comment: Yes. Hopefully my cautionary disclaimer in the answer is discouragement enough.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll definitely take your advice and not use the filter. What do you think would be best - a directive? doing it in each controller?

Comment: Yes, a directive, if you need reusability. But, if this is just a single place where you need (say, to show the currently logged in user), the a partial with `ng-include` should be sufficient.