# How can I create a server-side filter in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, server-side

I want to create a filter for my search input-field.
The data is on the server and the filter shall to filter the result from the server.
Currently I've created a variable "res" which has the Resource of my API with the method PUT.

I've created a input field with ng-model="searching" and in my table I've added a ng-repeat "data in datalist | search: searching"

I know that the Filter has the following scaffolding:

```
.filter('search', function () {
    return function (input, searchtext) {
        return ...;
    };
});
```

Can anyone give me a hint what I have to do?

Comment: Unless you're wanting to filter the data before the server gives it to angular, there's nothing server-related to this question. You simply want to filter an array. That may help your search results.

Comment: Without knowing how your searchtext should be used to filter your resultset, there isn't much we can do to help you.

Comment: You are essentially asking about creating an async filter - it's possible, but not a good idea. I've answered a similar question sometime ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27632022/968155

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? I'm new in Angularjs sorry :)... I have the problem when I use your solution the filter filtered only the first site, because I have a Pagination in my table list. How can I solve that?

Comment: You really need to clarify exactly what it is you are trying to do. Between the question being vague and code incomplete there isn't enough information here at all to understand your issue. Add to that you mention `server filter` but angular runs in the browser and `PUT` is used for updates generally...very confusing

Comment: @charlietfl please look on my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with server-side. But you may achieve what you want with a built-in angular filter, like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="Filter..." />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: query">
        {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/llLirkqIJmEWAue0QdVk?p=preview

If you have complex objects, you can also use the same bult-in filter, like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="Filter..." />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { name: query }">
        {{ item.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/L7DMn0xncHDQqyXDD0TR?p=preview

Comment: The problem is I have a List about items. The list is paginated and when I'm using your solution the filter filtered only the first site. In my example each site has a maximum of 20 items. Your filter displays only the result from the first site.

Answer (score 0):

That's my consideration:

index.html:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchText">
```

test.html (here is my form):

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="data in datalist | offset: (currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage | search: searchText">
...
```

and in my Filter-File I have:

```
.filter('search', ['$scope', '$resource', '$http', 'apiHost', function ($scope, $resource, $http, apiHost) {
    return function (input) {
        var url = $resource(apiHost + '/:id', {
            id: '@id'
        });

        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            data: input
        };

        $http(req).success(function (data) {
            var dataresult = data;
        });
        return dataresult;
    };
}]);
```

I thought, I need all the data from the backend, because what I'm telling before, the default filter (not my custom filter) gets only the result of the first pagination site. For example when I'm looking for a category with the name "test" and the category is on Pagination page 2 the filter doesn't find the data with the category "test" on page 2.

Comment: don't create an answer to clarify your question. Update the question instead. This is not an answer. You can't use `filter()` to make server requests. Also the code shown will always return undefined the function will return `dataresult` before the request is done